# Topology, $(\mathbb{Z},\tau_p)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $p$ be a prime number.

a) Show, that for every set of the form

$A(n,\alpha):=\{m\in\mathbb{Z}:m=n+qp^\alpha\quad\text{for a}\,\,q\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ is a base for a topology $\tau_p$ with topological space $\mathbb{Z}$.

b) $(\mathbb{Z},\tau_p)$ is metrisable.

Hello,

I have a question to this task.
I am not sure what I have to do. I think I need to give the topology $\tau_p$ first, before I can prove that the sets $A(n,\alpha)$ are a base of this topology.

But is there a set $A(n,\alpha)=\emptyset$. 
How can this be a base, when you have no set, which is empty.
To be a base means, that every set of $\tau_p$ (so espacially $\emptyset$) is a collection of sets from the given form $A(n,\alpha)$. When this does not contain the $\emptyset$ itself, how can it be a base, or am I mistaken.

But besides that, do I have to give the topology $\tau_p$ on my own?

Thanks in advance for your feedback and tips.

Comment: A basis need not to contain the empty set, look up at the definition.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal B$ is a base for a topology on a set $X$ if and only if the set of all unions of sets drawn from $\mathcal B$ forms a topology on $\mathcal B$.

This includes the empty union - the union of no sets from $\mathcal B$, which is the empty set.

Do you know this equivalent definition of a basis?

> A set $\mathcal B\subset\mathcal P(X)$ is a base for some topology on $X$ if and only if whenever $U,V\in \mathcal B$, the intersection $U\cap V$ may be written as (possibly infinite) union $\bigcup_i U_i$, where $U_i\in\mathcal B$ for all $i$.

In order for this definition to work, we should not require the empty set to be contained in $\mathcal B$.

Comment: Yes, I know this equivalent definition. Thanks, now it is clear how it is meant. Do I need to give a possible topology $\tau_p$ and then show that the sets $A(n,\alpha)$ are a base?

Comment: There's only one choice of possible topology $\tau_p$ that has $\{A(n,\alpha\}$ as a base, and that's the set of all sets that are unions of some collection of $A(n,\alpha)$.  You can either show that this $\tau_p$ is a topology or you can show that the equivalent condition is satisfied by the $A(n,\alpha)$.  It might be a good idea to do it both ways - you should find that the arguments are very similar.

Comment: I have a question to the set $A(n,\alpha)$. Do you chose fixed $\alpha$ and $p$ for every set and just the $n$ individually, or is the $n$ fixed to and just the $q$ is variable.

Comment: @MrTopology $p$ is fixed througout.  Otherwise, you choose $n$ and $\alpha$ arbitrarily for each set.

Comment: Thanks. When I now want to show that the set of all collections of $A(n,\alpha)$. I have to show, that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are in $\tau_p=\{\bigcup_{i\in I} A(n_i,\alpha_i): I\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\}$ did I denote the set right? $\emptyset\in\tau_p$ when you chose $I=\emptyset$. And $\mathbb{Z}\in\tau_p$ because you can chose $I=\mathbb{Z}$ and q=0 and collect every integers that way.

Comment: @MrTopology That's all correct.

Comment: But how can I show now, that for $U, V\in\tau_p\Rightarrow U\cap V$ and for $\mathcal{U}\subseteq\tau_p\Rightarrow \bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}} U\in\tau_p$. The last should be easy, because of the construction of $\tau_p$ which already includes every collection of those sets. But how do I get the intersection. I tried to make an example to understand what is happening, but it kinda confused me even more...

Comment: The union case is easy.  For the intersection case, try to show that $A(n,\alpha)\cup A(n',\alpha')$ can be written as the union of $A(n_i,\alpha_i)_{i\in I}$.

Comment: You might instead try to do part b) first; i.e., choose a metric on $\mathbb Z$ such that the $A(n,\alpha)$ are precisely the open balls for that metric.  The open balls in a metric space are always a base for the topology on that space, so (a) you get a topology on $\mathbb Z$ with the $A(n,\alpha)$ as a base and (b) that topology is automatically metrizable.

Comment: That sounds interesting. But how can I construct such a metric, that $A(n,\alpha)$ are exactly the open balls. Do you have a hint?

Comment: @MrTopology This will be the last hint I give you, but try first considering the case $n=0$.